# Question on Java automatic update procedure

Tags: java

I want to ask on how exactly the java updates are done.
I mean, ok they are done automatically, but which part/how exactly does this process happen?
To give a specific example why I am asking this:
I have a java project that has as part of it, the specific jre that it needs and uses that at runtime so that there is no expectation of what Java is installed in the system, if it is installed etc.
The project's jre is part of the project's deployment i.e. not under `C:\Program Files\jre` for instance.
I am starting to wonder if in this case the update process will work i.e. the project's jre will actually be updated by the java scheduler (?) or what is that does the update or not.
So will it happen automatically or this is something I have to take into consideration??
Any input is highly welcome

**UPDATE:**
I do not want to avoid the update!!!
I am interested to know if in my case the automatic update will actually happen or there is a configuration needed specifically for my case

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > First Question I would ask is:

How do you plan to install the application? Don't you need the native JRE to install your own JRE and your java application? It sounds like a [chicken and egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) scenario.

> I am starting to wonder if in this case the update process will work
>   i.e. the project's jre will actually be updated by the java scheduler
>   (?) or what is that does the update or not.

No, the automatic JRE update (if that's how it's set on that client machine) should not impact your application. I am assuming you are launching the JVM with hard coded path to your self packaged JRE.

> So will it happen
>   automatically or this is something I have to take into consideration??

The regular client JRE updates will happen automatically if that's how it's set up on the machine. You will not need to worry about it **unless** your application interacts with the browsers (or other system applications that utilizes native JRE) since they will by default use the system/OS JRE and not your packaged ones. Your packaged JRE will obviously stay at the same version unless you update it with your application updates.

> > some advice:

I am not sure why you are packaging the JRE with your distribution. Most machines now a days have JRE pre-installed. Perhaps you can explain your application scenario to us. Also this contradicts the principles of platform independence.

Comment: CoolBean:Concerning your first point, no I do not need the JRE to install mine.I just have the JRE folder with everything in it.Now there is a misunderstanding.I actually want my JRE to be updated and not avoid it.I will update the post.I am not sure if this is possible with the JRE as I mention.Is it?Is configuration needed?Concerning your last question you are more or less correct.This is something I inherited and I believe that they needed to make sure that for instance Java5 is not in the deployed machine since all features are from Java6.One example is this

Comment: CoolBean:You are also right, the path to JRE is hard coded to link to my jre

Comment: @user384706: As I mentioned - you cant get automatic updates if your JRE is packaged with the app. You can manually send updates to the client machines for your app where you can update the JRE.

Comment: This is useful info for me.You mean that all I can do is just deliver the updated JRE as part of a next installation?Isn't there any program inside the JRE that one could manually run to download the updates?Does't juched.exe do that?Or for my case this will not work either?

Comment: @user384706: Correct. `jucheck.exe` and `jusched.exe` are the two services that performs the updates. There may be some hacks to get do it otherwise but I cant think of any at the moment.

Comment: Ok.It is just that it is not clear to me what do you mean by need of hack.If someone just runs the `jucheck.exe` and `jusched.exe` why would that not work?Manual update.Or there is a gap in my understanding in what happens underneath and it will fail without the hacks?And what would the hacks be?

Comment: You need to read this[FAQ](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/faq.html) to get a better idea.

Comment: Read the FAQ.Did not get the impression that there is a manual update (besides `Update Now` in the control panel).It says that the `jucheck.exe` and `jusched.exe` run automatically and transparent to the user.Who starts them?I wonder if I can start them manually

Comment: user384706: Starting windows services usually require admin accounts on that box if I recall correctly. And also you will need to figure out how to make the automatic updater copy the files to your application JRE. So it's not a trivial task by any means.

Comment: @user384706 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1516/discussion-between-coolbeans-and-user384706)

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by "specific JRE", rt.jar or something else ?

I think you take it from the wrong end - if the update can be a problem for you, why you just don't set you environment so the update does not affect your application whatever it modifies ?

Comment: Actually he wants to get the updates applied to his internally packaged JRE and delivered by Java automatic update scheduler (jusched.exe). He is not trying to avoid the JRE updates. So basically he wants to know if there is a way to make the Java automatic update do both the native JRE update as well as his own packaged one.